# xrandr: randr is missing after installing xorg

Tags: xorg, xvfb, randr

I am attempting to run xrandr because online it says you need `xrandr` to run `lwjgl`. However, whenever I try running `xrandr` it gives me the following error:

```
RandR extension missing
```

I tried running the following script:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
y
```

And it still doesn't work.
As a website said to do, I edited a file, which strangely did not exist already, and put in the following:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    screen 0 "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option "Composite" "Enable"
    Option "RANDR" "Enable"
    Option "Xinerama" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Here is the file I use to run Xvfb:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log

[program:xvfb]
command=/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x864x16 -ac -pn -noreset +extension RANDR -extension XINERAMA

[program:x11vnc]
command=x11vnc -shared -rfbport 5900 -display :99 -forever

[program:novnc]
command=./desktop/noVNC/utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900 --listen %(ENV_PORT)s

[program:openbox]
command=fluxbox
environment=DISPLAY=":99"
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Updated to 14.04.5. Removed my xorg file. Uninstalled 7 packages, including plymouth, udev, couchdb, etc. Did this because of an annoying dialog 'hotplug support required'.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       t